# How to make an object blink once in js?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm not proficient in js to say the very least.

I have a bouncy ball in a container in js. When the ball hits a certain part of its container, I want a box to light up briefly. I want to control the duration of the blink. I want the blink to happen once.

So far this works but the blink is incredibly brief:

I have a canvas object

```
<Canvas id="button1" width="100px" height="50px"></canvas>
```

And this code in place. Let's assume for simplicity's sake that the ball being in the right place sets ball_is_in_area to T for a very short duration.

```
var button1;
var button1ctx;
var ball_is_in_area = F;

button1 = document.getElementById("button1");  
button1ctx = button1.getContext("2d");
button1ctx.fillStyle = "white";
button1ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 

if( ball_is_in_area == T){
  snd.play();
  button1ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  button1ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

"Don't use a canvas object use X" type answers are also appreciated!

Comment: Code "inspired" by https://code.sololearn.com/WfVExz4DcU0G/#html

Comment: Don't get too "inspired" by that code because it's wrong and quite ugly. To say "don't use a canvas" we would really need to know what you're trying to do. If you're designing a game, for instance, it makes sense. For other things it may not. When using `canvas`, you basically have to redraw the whole thing on each frame. You know when it's time to redraw using `requestAnimationFrame`, not with a loop. That said, it's a matter of knowing _where in the animation_ you are on each frame (did I hit the wall the last frame?) to tell if you have to redraw the ball in a way or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and based on [this sample](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript/Bounce_off_the_walls), you can use the timestamp parameter provided and, whenever you hit a wall, extend the timer for when the blink will end. Then use this timer to determine the color of the background.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width / 2, y = canvas.height / 2;
var ballRadius = 10, dx = 2, dy = -2;
var blinkDuration = 60; // Duration in milliseconds
var endBlink = 0;

function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw(timeStamp) {
  if (x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
    endBlink = timeStamp + blinkDuration; // Hit a wall
    dx = -dx;
  }
  if (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius || y + dy < ballRadius) {
    endBlink = timeStamp + blinkDuration;
    dy = -dy;
  }

  // If endBlink > timeStamp, change the color
  ctx.fillStyle = (endBlink > timeStamp ? "#338" : "#114");
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBall();

  x += dx;
  y += dy;
  
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```css
body { margin: 0 }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="630" height="190"></canvas>
```